# Facebook Messenger download

Tags: pdf, html, facebook

I have downloaded a Facebook Messenger conversation to my Mac laptop in HTML format and saved as a PDF. The conversation contains hundreds of messages and images. Is there some way I can reverse the order to view the oldest message at the top of the conversation?

Comment: This is not a web app question but a data manipulation question.  You want to know how to reverse the order of content in an HTML file.  I expect there is a way to do it using a script, or importing to a spreadsheet etc.

Comment: Thank you Blind Spots. I did try importing into a spreadsheet, but the 150 or so images along with the conversation didn't give me a satisfactory result. Mind you, I am a mental midget when it comes to this stuff, so I probably did something wrong. I'm unfamiliar with using a script but happy to learn :-)

Comment: It would be helpful if your question contained a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  For example a [code block]  containing the complete HTML page but reduced down to only 3 messages,  substituting  any identifying text with generic versions.  The key here is that the help needn't come from a Facebook user and regardless if they do use FB, providing the necessary code will encourage more people to help as it reduces the overhead required of them to engage. 

Comment: I know nothing of MREs or code blocks I'm afraid. That sounds like a foreign language to me. I have commenced the laborious task of copying and pasting into a word document, starting from the bottom (earliest post) and working upwards to include the images.  I thank you for taking the time to assist Blind Spots.